# unabel to share a folder in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: file-sharing, connection-sharing

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 , i want to enable sharing for a folder , when i RIGHT CLICK the folder i wont get any sharing options ,is there any another way to make a folder to share.
 I want to share it between my vmbox which runs windows7 OS.

Is There any terminal command to enable sharing .

```
                       thank you
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sharing option is provided by the nautilus-share package. Its possible that it might be missing. Try

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-share
```

Comment: yes ,I installed the nautilus-share and I restart my system , when i right clicked I got "LOCAL NETWORK SHARE".  you helped me a lot and the problem what you understood is correct. thank you

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark the query as solved by marking my answer?

Answer (score 0):

right click the folder and go to properties 
there will be four tabs in the window that will come up
[the properties window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvFVd.png)
you can change sharing properties here

Comment: I already seen it , i got only Basic and permissions , only two tabs